# Ambiguity between list, and list. How do I fix this?

Tags: c#, .net

Ok so here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Phonebook
{
    struct PhoneBookEntry
    {
        public string name;
        public string phone;
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private List<PhoneBookEntry> phoneList =
            new List<PhoneBookEntry>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Reads PhoneList.txt, and stores its objects in phoneList.
        private void ReadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader inputFile;
                string line;

                PhoneBookEntry entry = new PhoneBookEntry();

                char[] delim = { ',' }; //Create array.

                inputFile = File.OpenText("PhoneList.txt"); //Open the .txt file.

                //Read file.
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //Read line from file.
                    line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                    //Tokenize the line.
                    string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                    //Store tokens in the entry object.
                    entry.name = tokens[0];
                    entry.phone = tokens[1];

                    //Add it to the list.
                    phoneList.Add(entry);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        //Display names.
        private void DisplayNames()
        {
            foreach (PhoneBookEntry entry in phoneList)
            {
                nameListBox.Items.Add(entry.name);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReadFile(); //Read PhoneList.txt
            DisplayNames(); //Display names.
        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

It's meant to take a file, read every line, stick it in the list box, and then when the name is clicked show the number. Problem is that VS is spamming the following error:

```
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.cs    71
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.cs    59
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.Designer.cs   31
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.Designer.cs   40
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.Designer.cs   41
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.Designer.cs   42
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.Designer.cs   43
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.Designer.cs   44
Error   CS0229  Ambiguity between 'Form1.phoneList' and 'Form1.phoneList'   Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.Designer.cs   92
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Phonebook.Form1.phoneList' because 'Phonebook.Form1.phoneList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'  Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.cs    71
Error   CS0103  The name 'nameListBox' does not exist in the current context    Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.cs    73
Error   CS0102  The type 'Form1' already contains a definition for 'phoneList'  Phonebook   D:\Google Drive\VS Projects\Phonebook\Phonebook\Form1.cs    23
```

This project is for my C# introduction course, and I made sure that everything is correct, but I just can't get it to work properly. What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you have a control with the name "phoneList"?

Comment: @B.K. Yes. The listbox is called "phoneList".

Comment: Ah, simple fix then.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Error   CS0102  The type 'Form1' already contains a definition for 'phoneList'
```

You have a control with name `phoneList` and your have a List with the name `phoneList`.  The compiler does not know which one you mean.  Name one of them something different.

One of the conventions I've seen being used (and I do that sometimes) is to use a control type abbreviation as a suffix or prefix.  For example:

phoneList_lb, lbPhoneList, phoneListLb

Just something that would tell you that you're not dealing with something in the code, bur rather a control.

Comment: plus 1for lbPhoneList, underscore suffixes are ugly! personal opinion though.

Comment: @Ryios you're going to hate what I have to say. For starters, c# is strongly typed. Hungarian notation is unnecessary and just plain annoying. Public or protected properties and fields should be pascal case, e.g. PhoneListBox. The variable name tells you it's a list box control. Private fields should be camel case, and many prefer start with an underscore, e.g. _phoneList. This is to differentiate from parameters and local private variables that are just camel case with no underscore, e.g. phoneList.

Comment: I use _ on private fields that back properties.  On fields that do not back properties I use camel case "thisIsaField".  I never make public fields, it's c# if you need it public expose it with a property.  I use ThisIsAProperty on properties.  I only use the txtFirstName on the private field the form designer makes for you.  And I do it in html because html pages can get massive, and in javascript I want to know that txtJobState is an input tag without having to type out jobStateInput.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mistakenly name a ListBox control in your form designer as phoneList and you declare another List named phoneList.

Name the control differently. Each control you create on designer will have its respective variable declaration with the same name.

Name the control phoneListBox, then set the value:

```
phoneListBox.Items.AddRange(phoneList.ToArray());
```